# Selenium WebDriver Can't Click Button

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, button

I'm trying to automate a messaging system on Etsy and am running into trouble with my code. I receive error messages that the reCaptcha element can't be found, which I think means that my code didn't successfully click the messaging button in the first place.

I've tried using xpath, id, class names, etc but I still can't figure out how to click the "message button".

here's the [Messaging Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMGxM.png) and the [Messaging Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJqK3.png)

```
url = 'https://www.etsy.com/sg-en/listing/794585057/lavender-chamomile-shower-steamers-sleep?ga_order=most_relevant&ga_search_type=all&ga_view_type=gallery&ga_search_query=green+beauty&ref=sc_gallery-1-2&plkey=2bab0193d5d13095397b2acdab033b78a0d0f30b%3A794585057&cns=1'
wd.get(url)
last_height = wd.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight;")  

time.sleep(3)

#loading the page
wd.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, arguments[0]);',last_height/3)
time.sleep(3)
wd.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, arguments[0]);',last_height/3 + last_height/3)
time.sleep(3)
wd.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, arguments[0]);',last_height)
time.sleep(3)

#clicking on the "Message Seller" button 
html = wd.page_source
wd.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='desktop_shop_owners_parent']/div/a").click()
time.sleep(3)

#clicking on the reCaptcha button
wd.find_element_by_id("recaptcha-anchor").click()

time.sleep(1)
 
#typing in a test message 
open_message = wd.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='chat-ui-composer']/div[1]/div[1]/textarea").click()
open_message.sendKeys('hi (-: ')
wd.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='chat-ui composer']/div[1]/div[2]/button").click()


#marker to show that message has been sent
brand = wd.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='desktop_shop_owners_parent']/div/div/div[2]/p[1]").text
print('messaged: ' + brand)

wd.quit()
```

Would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

```
wd.find_element_by_css_selector('[class="wt-btn wt-btn--filled wt-mb-xs-0"]').click()
wd.find_element_by_xpath(
    "//*[@id='desktop_shop_owners_parent']/div/a").click()
```

you are using find_elements , change it to find element also have to close the accept cookies pop up

Full code:

```
url = 'https://www.etsy.com/sg-en/listing/539990072/chamomile-flowers-matraurea-umbellatum?ref=sold_out-10'
wd.get(url)
last_height = wd.execute_script(
    "return document.documentElement.scrollHeight;")

time.sleep(3)

#loading the page
wd.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, arguments[0]);', last_height/3)
time.sleep(3)
wd.execute_script(
    'window.scrollTo(0, arguments[0]);', last_height/3 + last_height/3)
time.sleep(3)
wd.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, arguments[0]);', last_height)
time.sleep(3)

#clicking on the "Message Seller" button
html = wd.page_source
wd.find_element_by_css_selector(
    '[class="wt-btn wt-btn--filled wt-mb-xs-0"]').click()

time.sleep(4)
wd.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='desktop_shop_owners_parent']/div/a").click()
time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: thanks! changed it but i'm still not able to find the element - any ideas?

Comment: @codinggirl because that item is sold! . I added full code for another item try that

Comment: really appreciate your help! still not working )-:

Comment: its working till this code please try again